# How can I make testRigor find these inputs?

Tags: web-testing, testrigor

I'm trying to make testRigor put some data into some inputs. The thing is that it has found some of them but some it has not found.

Here I'll post an image where I show you the INPUTS testRigor has found and not found.

How can I make it found the ones I marked in red? PLease, help me.

Thanks!!!

[image: testRigor inputs found and not found]

Here is the current code (I marked the lines with *** the found and not found):

```
login
click on the "arrow" on the left of "Notas Fiscais"
click "Compra de mercadoria"
click "Selecione um cadastro"
click "AWISE (AWISE SOLUÇÕES TECNOLÓGICAS LTDA)"
click "Informar custos adicionais"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into "Frete" and save as "Fretes"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into "Seguro" and save as "Seguros"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into "Outras Despesas" and save as "OutrasDespesas"
click "Continuar"
click "Selecione um produto"
click "eerenlkrwlfxr"
generate by regex "[1-9]{3}", then enter into the first input "1" and save as "quantidadeProdutos" ***FOUND***
generate by regex "[1-9]{5}", then enter into the second input "R$" and save as "custoProdutos" ***FOUND***
click "Selecione um produto"
enter "Gerar Nome Produto aquiiii" into "Pesquisar..."
click "Adicionar produto Gerar Nome Produto aquiiii"
generate by regex "[a-z]{10,18}", then enter into "Nome" and save as "produtoNomes"
generate by regex "[1-9]{2}", then enter into "Estoque mínimo" and save as "EstoqueMínimo"
click "Estoque"
generate by regex "[1-9]{2}", then enter into "Estoque" and save as "Estoque"
generate by regex "[1-9]{6}", then enter into "Código interno" and save as "CódigoInternoProduto"
click "Dados Fiscais"
click "Selecione um NCM"
enter "camisa" into "Pesquisar..."
click "61059000: Camisas de malha de outs.materias textei"
click "Precificação"
generate by regex "[1-3]{3}", then enter into "Custo Médio" and save as "CustosMédios"
generate by regex "[4-9]{3}", then enter into "Preço de venda" and save as "PreçosDeVenda"
click "Continuar"
click "Selecione um cadastro"
click "AWISE (AWISE SOLUÇÕES TECNOLÓGICAS LTDA)"
click "Adicionar Fornecedor"
click "Selecione um cadastro"
click "azlqceulwspp (mttcgndmbnznfy)"
click "Revisar"
click "Salvar"
generate by regex "[1-9]{3}", then enter into the fourth input "1" below "Qtd" and save as "quantidadeProdutos" ***NOT FOUND***
generate by regex "[1-9]{5}", then enter into the fifth input "R$" below "Vl. Un" and save as "custoProdutos" ***NOT FOUND***
generate by regex "[1-9]{3}", then enter into the sixth input "0,00" below "Desconto" and save as "custoProdutos" ***FOUND***
click "Continuar"
click "à vista"
click "entrada + parcelas"
enter "R$ 300,00" into "Missing translation \"financial.simplified_payments"
enter "2" into "Número de Parcelas"
click "Dinheiro" below the "Forma de pagamento"
click "Cartão de Crédito"
click "Continuar"
click "Continuar"
click "Salvar"
click "Precificar Produtos"
click "Nenhum produto selecionado"
click "Selecionar Todos"
click "Configurar Margem"
click "Configurar margem (%)" near the "Vendas Mercadorias Notas Fiscais Financeiro Ocorre"
enter "100" into "ember7979"
click "2 produtos selecionados"
click "Atualizar valor de venda de acordo com a margem co"
click "Nenhum produto selecionado"
click "Selecionar Todos"
click "Arredondar valor de venda"
click "Final 9,99"
click "Concluir"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case table-based references should be used:

```
enter "my data" into table at row containing stored value "my_generated_id" and column "Qtd"
```

Comment: All the IDs are ember genetared so they're not the same.
I tried this:
generate by regex "[1-9]{3}", then enter into table at row "2" column "Qtd."
But it did not work :(

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs I'm talking about the name of the generated "name" in "Item" column

Comment: this is a name generated using the 'generate by regex' of testRigor here:
generate by regex "[a-z]{10,18}", then enter into "Nome" and save as "produtoNomes"
could you please give me an example how can I do this?